# Business Intelligence Datasource Performance - Large Table

Tags: performance, tableau-api, business-intelligence, query-performance, sqlperformance

I use Tableau and have a table with 140 fields. Due to the size/width of the table, the performance is poor. I would like to remove fields to increase reading speed, but my user base is so large, that at least one person uses each of the fields, while 90% use the same ~20 fields.

What is the best solution to this issue? (Tableau is our BI tool, BigQuery is our database)

What I have done thus far:
In  Tableau, it isn't clear how to user dynamic data sources that change based on the field selected. Ideally, I would like to have smaller views OR denormalized tables. As the users makes their selections in Tableau, the underlying data sources updates to the table or view with that field.

I have tried a simple version of a large view, but that performed worse than my large table, and read significantly more data (remember, I am BigQuery, so I care very much about bytes read due to costs)

Comment: Are you sure it's the table width that is the problem? I read bigquery doco for 10 seconds  and it didn't mention width. Have you tested to confirm that narrower tables are faster? Doesn't Tableau only select the fields it needs?

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid. You are completely correct that width isn't necessarily an issue. However, larger width leads to higher cardinality in my case. That is why I want to trim down as much as possible. And, also true - Tableau shows only the selected field. However, same as above, that field may be 1.5X longer due to additional fields which increase cardinality. Appreciate the thought! Keep it coming .

Comment: Its not just that Tableau only shows the fields used in the viz - it only queries the data source about those fields. You can think of the Tableau data source as defining a family of possible SQL queries, and that Tableau generates an optimized SQL query based on the fields you actually used in that view. So having many columns is not necessarily costly.

Comment: Two tips 1. If your database enforces referential integrity (e.g. no foreign keys to non-existent rows), then Tableau can generate more efficient SQL if you select the "Assume Referential Integrity" option from the Data menu. Esp. useful for star and snowflake schemas. 2. Use the Tableau Performance Recording (under the help menu) or the Tableau Log Viewer (open source app) to see the actual SQL that is generated. To evaluate performance, paste it into a SQL client and experiment, look at a query plan, check statistics, etc - make sure the generated SQL really is the problem first.

Comment: Again I'm no bigquery expert but _larger width leads to higher cardinality in my case_ doesn't make sense to me. Cardinality is not columns, it's rows. Unless you are saying the data model has some kind of cross-product design flaw?

Comment: Thanks, @Nick.McDermaid for responding. For me, the more columns I have, leads to more unique row values, which is what I meant by higher cardinality.

Comment: Are you saying you are _always_ running `distinct` in the query? There's a fundamental performance issue right there.

Comment: you didn't mention if you are using any filtering options?

Comment: @AlexBlakemore I never thought of that approach. My current process is to take large views, then denormalize and flatten via select *. This gets me a native table which performs better, albeit it in includes EVERYTHING. When using as a view instead, the performance got worse while using Assume Referential Integrity. That is a great feature to know, though. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

**Suggestion 1:** Extract your data.

Especially when it comes to datasources which are pay per query byte, (Big Query, Athena, Etc) extracts make a great deal of sense. Depending how 'fresh' the data must be for the users. (Of course all users will say 'live is the only way to go', but dig into this a little and see what it might actually be.) Refreshes can be scheduled for as little as 15 minutes. The real power of refreshes comes in the form of 'incremental refreshes' whereby only new records are added (along an index of int or date.) This is a great way to reduce costs - if your BigQuery database is partitioned - (*which it should be.*)  Since Tableau Extracts are contained within .hyper files, a structure of Tableau's own design/control, they are extremely fast and optimized perfectly for use in Tableau.

**Suggestion 2:** Create 3 Data Sources (or more.) Certify these datasources after validating that they provide correct information. Provide users with with clear descriptions.

1. Original Large Dataset.
2. Subset of ~20 fields for the 90%.
3. Remainder of fields for the 10%
4. Extract of 1
5. Extract of 2
6. Extract of 3

Importantly, if field names match in each datasource (ie: not changed manually ever) then it should be easy for a user to 'scale up' to larger datasets as needed. This means that they could generally always start out with a small subset of data to begin their exploration, and then use the '[replace datasource](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/connect_basic_replace.htm)' feature to switch to a different datasource while keeping their same views. (This wouldn't work as well if at all for scaling down, though.)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Suggestion 1 would definitely be ideal. However, the issue is that creating extracts on large cardinality tables in BigQuery has proved unsuccessful. It takes 30+ minutes to extract 1.5million records. My small table is 350million records. Suggestion 2 is where I was leaning, but was hoping to avoid upkeep of multiple tables. However, I am starting to think this may be the best approach.

Comment: How long does it take to complete a SELECT * of the same 1.5 million rows of data BigQuery itself?

Comment: I am trying to tag you, but am having a heckuva time doing so. Maybe 2 minutes tops? I have had many issues extracting data from BigQuery. I have found better performance in databases like Postgres (which is insane considering how good BigQuery is overall).

Comment: Yeah, its surprising then that you'd see a 30 minute extract time. How about network architecture between Tableau and BigQuery? (Proxy, Load Balancer, Firewall, etc?) Your network team might be able to find/explain the difference in speeds.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea. I will continue researching and see if there is something better that can be done. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Any additional info from the network team? Very curious about this one.

Comment: Network team confirmed we are wide open. No issues there. The issue appears to be around column width. That is, the more columns, the less extract performance. For example - I ran an extract on a Teradata db, 300million records took 45 minutes for a similar amount of columns. BigQuery took 30 minutes for 1.5million records. BigQuery does not perform well against width.